# How to work with parent-depended style with Reach Router

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this structure in my app:

```
  <Parent style={{display 'flex'}}>
      <Child style={{flex: 1}}></Child>
  </Parent>
```

We're using Reach Router in our app, and we wrap the `Child` component with `<Router/>`.
The problem with that is`<Router/>` render another div between the parent and the child, and basically 'block' the flex 1 property.

```
  <Parent style={{display 'flex'}}>
     <Header/>
      <Router>
        <Child style={{flex: 1}}></Child>
      </Router>
     <Footer/>
  </Parent>
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

you can read about fragments here https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

you can use the tag <> and </>.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<div>` tag outside `Child`

```
<Parent>
  <Router>
    <div style={{display 'flex'}}>
      <Child style={{flex: 1}}></Child>
    <div/>
  </Router>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Router that deep is there a reason for it?

You could write something in the likes of:

```
// Main File
<Router>
    <App />
</Router>

// Your React Component
<Parent style={{display 'flex'}}><Child style={{flex: 1}} /></Parent>
```

Edit: after checking the code, for router, it seens it uses a prop defaulted to "div" you could change that.

```
let {
  location,
  navigate,
  basepath,
  primary,
  children,
  baseuri,
  component = "div",
  ...domProps
} = this.props;
```

So I think you could do the likes of:

```
const Parent = <Parent style={{display 'flex'}} />;

<Router component={Parent}>
    <Child style={{flex: 1}}></Child>
</Router>
```